# Order of range() arguments in python

Tags: python, range

I am wondering how the range() function in Python 2.7 is able to have a syntax like:

```
range(start, stop[, step])
```

As creating a function in Python requires the optional arguments to be at the end of the parameter entries, as in:

```
function(a, b, c=1)
```

(for some reason I can't find the file in which range() is declared so...)
But it is possible to enter only a single (stop) integer as in `range(10)`

Does range then use some construct like the one below? Or is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
def TestRange(start, stop = None, stepSize = 1):
    if stop == None:
        d = 0
        TrackTest = []
        while d < start:
            TrackTest += [d]
            d += stepSize
        return TrackTest
    else:
        d = start
        TrackTest = []
        while d < stop:
            TrackTest += [d]
            d += stepSize
        return TrackTest
```

Using the test cases below we get a (seemingly) similar result as that of using a range function.

```
print TestRange(6)
print TestRange(2, 6)
print TestRange(2, 6, 2)
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  In Python 3 `range` does not return a list, it returns a `range` object.  A generator would be appropriate for a Python 3 version (or Python 2 `xrange`)

Comment: I tried that and ended up concluding that creating a function in Python requires the optional arguments to be at the end of the parameter entries, as in `function(a, b, c=1)`. As `function(a=1, b, c=1)` is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for `range`  (this is the `range_new` function): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d741c6d3179b771cec8d47c7b01dd48181b7717e/Objects/rangeobject.c#L79

```
if (PyTuple_Size(args) <= 1) {
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "range", 1, 1, &stop))
        return NULL;
    stop = PyNumber_Index(stop);
    if (!stop)
        return NULL;
    start = PyLong_FromLong(0);
    if (!start) {
        Py_DECREF(stop);
        return NULL;
    }
    step = PyLong_FromLong(1);
    if (!step) {
        Py_DECREF(stop);
        Py_DECREF(start);
        return NULL;
    }
}
else {
    if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "range", 2, 3,
                           &start, &stop, &step))
        return NULL;

    /* Convert borrowed refs to owned refs */
    start = PyNumber_Index(start);
    if (!start)
        return NULL;
    stop = PyNumber_Index(stop);
    if (!stop) {
        Py_DECREF(start);
        return NULL;
    }
    step = validate_step(step);    /* Caution, this can clear exceptions */
    if (!step) {
        Py_DECREF(start);
        Py_DECREF(stop);
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

It is essentially the same approach as in your `TestRange`, although you can do `TestRange(stop, step=3)` but you can't do `range(stop, step=3)`, because the last argument to `range` is not actually a keyword arg.

Comment: So this is how it works. The code underlying the `range` function actually counts the number of arguments passed and acts based on that. But is there a way for someone to do something similar in Python right in a function definition? If so, what is it?